# How to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

My teacher told us that :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}=0$$

Without giving any proof

If someone could tell me how to approach this that would be great !

Comment: Use the fact that $\cos y$ is the real part of $e^{iy}$  and us ethe formula for a geometric sum.

Comment: The average for the vertices of a regular $n$-gon is the center.  In this case, take vertices $$\left(\cos\frac{2k\pi}{n},\sin\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)$$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$.  This is the same as Kavi's comment, but appropriate for a student not familiar with complex numbers.